# How to select only particular column in ui grid and highlight

Tags: user-interface, grid

Used `enableCellSelection: true` but it doesn't work it out.

```
$scope.gridOptionss = { data: 'dashboard',enableGridMenu: true,enableCellSelection: true, enableRowSelection: false, enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        columnDefs: [
            {field:'Name', displayName:'No Response',width:150},
            {field:'age', displayName:'Part Response', width:150},              
        ]
}
```